# pasing data from next js SSG to components gives a TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined error

Tags: next.js

bit of a weird error I'm having, I have a single `catchall` page, these pages are created via a cms. these pages all use SSG.

the catchall page looks like this :

```
export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async ({ params }) => {
  const slug = params!.catchall ?? 'index';

  const { data } = await FetchPageData(slug);

  return {
    props: {
      data,
    },
  };
};

export const getStaticPaths: GetStaticPaths = async () => {
  const { data } = await FetchAllPages();

  const paths = data.map(page => ({
    params: { catchall: [page.page_slug] },
  }));

  return {
    paths: paths,
    fallback: true,
  };
};
```

Now the error occurs when creating the actual `Page` component and exporting it:

```
This is the component that is exported by the catchall page

const Page: NextPage = ({
  data,
}: InferGetStaticPropsType<typeof getStaticProps>) => {
    return <MapLayout page={data} />;
};

export default Page;
```

If I export it like the above the error appears inside of the `Maplayout` component,

if I export it like the following :

```
const Page: NextPage = ({
  data,
}: InferGetStaticPropsType<typeof getStaticProps>) => {
  if (data){
    return <MapLayout page={data} />;
  }

  return <div>Loading</div>
};

export default Page;
```

The `TypeError` disappears BUT I have a second or so of `loading` before the actual page content shows up, this is of course not acceptable and seems to defeat the entire point of SSG?

Any idea on how to fix this issue ?

Comment: That's most likely because you're trying to access a page that wasn't pre-generated by `getStaticPaths`/`getStaticProps` at build time, meaning the fallback behaviour will get triggered since you're using `fallback: true`. You can either handle the fallback  page by checking [`router.isFallback`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-static-paths#fallback-pages), or just use `fallback: 'blocking'` instead in `getStaticPaths`.